# Any book which introduces physics historically?

Tags: resource-recommendations, history

I am reading Paul Nahin's "When Least Is Best" and I find the style really good. Is there any such book for physics?

In other words, I would like a book which describes the concepts of physics as how we reached them and how we had been so foolish initially. It can also include problems and its different methods attempted by different physicists.

If you have read the above mentioned book, you would better be able to know what I would like to have.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better place for this question?

Comment: No I don't think so. Isn't that more metaphysical? This is a serious physics question, I believe.

Comment: As in, all of physics, in a single book? That's a bit of a broad ask, no?

Comment: Well, not necessarily all physics. I just would like the book to have this style.

Comment: @KartikSharma What do you mean by "metaphysical"?  It's a site about the history of actual science.

Comment: A whiggish history of physics may not be the best way to get more insight...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics history book with some math](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18227/)

Comment: Abandoned concepts and theories were not necessarily "foolish." They were just superseded by concepts and theories which were better at explaining or predicting, or in some cases just more popular. Physics is not something which is discovered, like an unexplored continent. It is something which is constructed, like a building. Perhaps what you want is a book on the philosophy of science.  eg [The Structure of Scientific Revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions).

Comment: @sammygerbil No, "foolish" is a self thought which comes to every physicist or mathematician after they have discovered something. Yes, to a third person it does feel so systematic to reach the solution but to the man himself, it feels like enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

[QED and the men who made it](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5524.html) gives a great historical account of the early history of quantum electrodyanmics.

The book sketches the personalities of Dyson, Feynman, Schwinger, and Tomonaga  and many of their students. They also show the derivations that were made by those pioneers without to much "modernization". (Note that this makes the book rather difficult to understand)

I would definitely recommend this book but it is by no means easy to read lecture.