# Evolution of theories in physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, string-theory, resource-recommendations, history

I am searching for a book on the theories of (high energy) physics to gain insight, why they are so powerful.
Namely, I would like to find a book that uses the evolution of physics from classical theories (e.g. electromagnetism) to String Theory, to show why new theories were necessary and how physicist were able to formulate them (guiding principles)

As a physicist I am aware of these theories but I would like to find literature that points out in a concise way :

- The important experiments that led to new physical models
- What are the consistency conditions theoretical physics developed to overcome the lack of experimental data
- Why are physical theories so powerful, while in trouble with math ( e.g. path integral formulation of QFT)

In the best case the literature is a combination of explaining these points intuitively, while using the most important math concepts to support the explanation.

Comment: Found this question with some interesting answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18227/physics-history-book-with-some-math?rq=1

Comment: I don't think this question should be put on hold. I remember how interesting and important it is to understand the development and history of science that I learnt from classical mechanics course in college. My teacher started way back from Aristotle and continued until the start of Quantum Field Theories. To the moderators, I would say please embrace such questions.